# Met "/bin/bash: no such file" when building docker image from scratch

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create my own docker image in a ubuntu-14 system.

My docker file is like the following:

```
FROM scratch
RUN /bin/bash -c 'echo "hello"'
```

I got the error message when I run `docker build .`:

`exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory`

I guess it is because `/bin/sh` doesn't exist in the base image "scratch". How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker is basically a **containerising** tool that helps to build systems and bring them up and running in a flash without a lot of resource utilisation as compared to Virtual Machines.

**A Docker container is basically a layered container.** In case you happen to read a Dockerfile, each and every command in that file will lead to a creation of a new layer in container and the final layer is what your container actually is after all the commands in the Dockerfile has been executed.

The images available on the Dockerhub are specially optimised for this sort of environment and are very easy to setup and build. In case you are building a container right from scratch i.e. without any base image, then what you basically have is an empty container. An empty container does not understand what ***/bin/bash*** actually is and hence it won't work for you.

The Docker container does not use any specifics from your underlying OS. Multiple docker containers will make use of the same underlying kernel in an effective manner. That's it. Nothing else.
**(** *There is however a concept of **volumes**  wherein the container shares a specific volume on the local underlying system* **)**

So in case you want to use /bin/bash, you need a base image which will setup the nitty gritties of this command for your container and then you can successfully execute it.

However, it is recommended that you use official Docker images for say Ubuntu and then install your custom stuff on top of it. The official images are right from the makers and are highly optimised for this environment.

Answer (score 2):

Base image `scratch` does not use `/bin/bash`. So you should change to:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN /bin/sh -c 'echo "hello"'
```

Comment: It didn't work either. Do you have any idea how this happened?

Comment: Did you try with `FROM ubuntu:14.04` ?

Comment: FROM ubuntu:14.04 works. I'm afraid this is the only way. I though there's some trick that can bring /bin/bash from host system to docker container. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: @NameTooLongException You're missing the point.... Containers are designed to isolate the running process from the host system. This is a good thing. If you need a bash shell, you either build it in (dumb) or use a base container that already contains it (smart). There are lighter images like busybox if you don't like ubuntu. Finally be careful not to over optimize. If you run lots and lots of containers using the same base image, that image is still only downloaded once. Much more efficient compared to downloading lots of bespoke base images.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment :) @MarkO'Connor